# What kind of tests does the OS perform on the keyboard during boot?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Today I spilled some water on my notebook computer. It worked fine for an hour afterwards, but then the keyboard went crazy: some keys stopped working, others were producing the wrong letter, or combinations of letters, infinite loops, etc.

Even if I immediately soaked up the spill, I am sure that some water got into the keyboard (my keyboard as a metal plate under it, so the water remained trapped in there). Since there is no way to disable a keyboard in windows 7 (if you uninstall the driver, it will be reinstalled by the OS at the next boot), I rebooted. My notebook beeped for a while during boot, but booted successfully. So the only option I had was to disconnect the keyboard from the MOBO and plug in a USB keyboard.

My question is about the beep: why did the computer beep during boot? I would think the OS would beep if no keyboard is found, but why if there is a keyboard (even when broken)? What kind of test is performed on the keyboard?

Comment: First of all, if you spill water on your notebook, immediately turn it off, unplug AC and battery and let it dry out for at least a day. Then, take it to a repair shop.

Comment: The OS does not perform any tests on the keyboard during boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) (not the OS) asks the keyboard to perform a self-test during [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

If the keyboard reports a problem, the BIOS beeps. Your keyboard is failing, so it's beeping to let you know something is wrong.

Since you spilled liquid into it you've probably shorted a path, causing a key to appear to be stuck down, which can/will cause the keyboard to report an error during POST.